# Why do I get a Key Error while loading my data?

Tags: python, lda, keyerror

I'm following this [tutorial for LDA](https://github.com/wjbmattingly/topic_modeling_textbook/blob/main/03_03_lda_model_demo.ipynb) and entered the following code

```
data = load_data("/home/export.json")["texts"]

print (data[0][0:90])
```

However, i get the following error message:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-0bbfa7176917> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 data = load_data("/home/export.json")["texts"]
      2 
      3 print (data[0][0:90])

KeyError: 'texts'
```

Even though other people always got Key Error messages, no one seemed to have it while loading the data so i couldn't find any previous posts talking about this particular issue.

Comment: Try `data = load_data("/home/export.json")`, then look at what keys the data has.